# Multiple studies in thinkscript combined into one study returns -

Tags: thinkorswim

I am making a query that includes all the bearish candles. I know some of the studies have entries, but when I do them all at once I get nothing.

```
input n = 0;

plot data =
AdvanceBlock()[n]
or DarkCloudCover()[n]
or Deliberation()[n]
or DownsideGapThreeMethods()[n]
or DownsideTasukiGap()[n]
or EveningDojiStar()[n]
or EveningStar()[n]
or FallingThreeMethods()[n]
or HangingMan()[n]
or IdenticalThreeCrows()[n]
or InNeck()[n]
or LowPriceGappingPlay()[n]
or OneBlackCrow()[n]
or OnNeck()[n]
or ShootingStar()[n]
or ThreeBlackCrows()[n]
or ThreeInsideDown()[n]
or ThreeoutsideDown()[n]
or Thrusting()[n]
or TwoCrows()[n]
or UpsideGapTwoCrows()[n]
;
```

[image]

[image]